# One checked check box only for each row

Tags: php, codeigniter, checkbox, html-table

I have a table where by each row has 3 columns: name, enable, disable. The enable and disable column have a check box and as the name states, I am trying to do only one ticked checkbox per row. These are my codes (for each row and for the two columns) so far:

```
<?php foreach($customers as $customer):?>
<tr>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $customer;?></td>
    <?php
    $check = FALSE;
    if($user_customer != FALSE)
        foreach($user_customer as $object)
            foreach($object as $current_customer)
                if($current_customer == $customer)
                    $check = TRUE;
    ?>

    <td align='center'>
        <?php
            if($check == FALSE)
                $data = array('name' => 'enable[]', 'value' => $customer, 'checked' => FALSE);
            else
                $data = array('name' => 'enable[]', 'value' => $customer,  'checked' => TRUE);

            echo form_checkbox($data);
        ?>
    </td>
    <td align='center'>
        <?php
            if($check == TRUE)
                $data = array('name' => 'disable[]', 'value' => $customer, 'checked' => FALSE);
            else
                $data = array('name' => 'disable[]',  'value' => $customer, 'checked' => TRUE);

            echo form_checkbox($data);
        ?>
    </td>

</tr>
<?php endforeach?>
```

After I submit my form it will store the values into the database accordingly however I do not want the user to be able to tick two check boxes at once. I tried using radio buttons but that limits to one check per column. I am trying to make it per row, any help?

P.S. I prefer not to use any Javascript.

EDIT, I added a counter for every row, so it'll be `radio_1` for the first row etc, this is the part I edited:

```
<td align='center'>
    <?php
        if($check == FALSE)
            $data = array('name' => "radio_$counter", 'value' => $customer, 'checked' => FALSE);
        else
            $data = array('name' => "radio_$counter", 'value' => $customer,  'checked' => TRUE);

        echo form_radio($data);
    ?>
</td>
<td align='center'>
    <?php
        if($check == TRUE)
            $data = array('name' => "radio_$counter", 'value' => $customer, 'checked' => FALSE);
        else
            $data = array('name' => "radio_$counter",  'value' => $customer, 'checked' => TRUE);

        echo form_radio($data);
    ?>
</td>
```

EDIT 2, this was how I used to retrieve it in my controller function:

```
// These were the arrays that I assigned to each checkbox according to the column
$enable = $this->input->post('enable');
$disable = $this->input->post('disable');

// I used it for inserting and deleting values
$insert = $this->home_model->insert_customer(array('user_id'=>$user_id, 'customer'=>$enable));
$delete = $this->home_model->delete_customer($user_id, $disable);
```

Comment: u shud use radio buttons only  and change their name in each row. may be use some counter or database id.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju What shoud I change the name to? I used two check boxes because if I used one I want to get the uncheck value also, if it's possible.

Comment: radio button name for first row = >radio_1, for second row, radio_2...etc

Comment: if required, i ll edit/answer for this.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju I've edited it, and yes please do. Now I'm stuck at how am I going to retrieve all the values when I submit the form. Previously as you can see I used an array for the names.

Comment: on submit, will you get multiple rows?? i mean is your table inside a form??

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju Yes my table is in a form, I want to get all the radio buttons values at once. Previously I used the name as an array so whatever was in that array previously I can use it in my controller. So now how do I retrieve it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92107/discussion-between-niranjan-n-raju-and-hzq).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I managed to solve my problem without using javascript.

First of all, in my view I use one hidden input and one checkbox input in the td. As you can see below, there are two different arrays. The hidden input array is named `disable[]` and the checkbox array which would contain all the checked checkbox value when form is submitted, is named `enable[]`.

The hidden input array `disable[]` will always submit the values no matter what. So now we have all the customer names in the `disable[]` array.

View:

```
<td align='center'>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $customer?>" name='disable[]'>
    <?php
        if($check == FALSE)
        {
            $data = array('name' => 'enable[]', 'value' => $customer, 'checked' => FALSE);
        }
        else
            $data = array('name' => 'enable[]', 'value' => $customer,  'checked' => TRUE);

        echo form_checkbox($data);
    ?>
</td>
```

Now this is where I manipulate the arrays to get the values I want. In my case, my database table has only two columns which is the `user_id` and `customer`. I just add and delete everytime the user wants to enable or disable his/her customer. That's why I want to get both arrays.

Controller:

```
// Array containing selected/checked customers
$enable = $this->input->post('enable');

// Array containing all customers
$disable = $this->input->post('disable');

// Loop through selected customers
foreach($enable as $index => $value)
{
    // Check if customer exists in database
    if( $this->home_model->check_customer($user_id, $enable[$index]) )
    {
        // If exists, unset from enable to prevent duplicate insert
        unset($enable[$index]);
    }

    /* Unset the remaining
    (or all selected customers if it doesn't exists in DB)
    selected customers from disable array */

    $key = array_search($value, $disable);
    unset($disable[$key]);
}
```

Now in the same controller, just do 3 simple checks to see whether the ensure which query to execute, like if there are customers to insert and delete, if there are only customers to insert, or if there are only customers to delete

```
// Check enable and disable array are not empty
if( ! empty($enable) && ! empty($disable) )
{
    $insert = $this->home_model->insert_customer(array('user_id'=>$user_id, 'customer'=>$enable));
    $delete = $this->home_model->delete_customer($user_id, $disable);
}
// If enable array is not empty but disable is empty, insert only
elseif( ! empty($enable) && empty($disable) )
{
    $insert = $this->home_model->insert_customer(array('user_id'=>$user_id, 'customer'=>$enable));
}
// If enable is empty but disable is not empty, delete only
elseif( empty($enable) && ! empty($disable) )
{
    $delete = $this->home_model->delete_customer($user_id, $disable);
}

/*** Proceed with whatever you want to do like go to new page etc ***/
```